# Is it possible to filter on a feed

Tags: getstream-io

Is it possible to implement filtering on feeds in stream? I would like to allow users to follow other user posts but have those tagged with various categories. The desire is to select a category of Football and see just the posts made by people I follow which have that tag or potentially a collection of tags if the category was All Sports for example.

Looking in the api and docs it seems that a feed is pivoted on a single attribute so I can do a request for all posts of people I follow but not all posts for people I follow that are about NCAA or NFL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the getstream-io api does not have any filtering capability for the retrieval of activities. All possible options for retrieval of activities can be found in the [REST docs](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#feed)

Comment: Is it still true as of today? :/